# should format requirements be in place for stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

I go on SO very often, and I like to help other people out more than I ask, that way I can guide new programmers to their full potential. I often provide multiple methods for doing something so that they can see what their problem was more clearly and also multiple ways of fixing it.

One problem I run into is there is a lot of code formatted like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main(){
    double a=0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"enter a number"<<endl;
        double b;
        cin>>b;
        a+=b;
    } a/=5;
    if(a==1){
        cout<<"a is 1">>endl;
    }else if(a==2){
        cout<<"a is 2">>endl;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            a%=2;
            string b="this is really bad code"
            cout>>b;
    }else{
       cout<<"a is not 1 o 2"<<endl;}
}
```

sorry for the really bad code, but I see this a lot. I think there should be an etiquette on how code should be formatted in order to be posted. I know style is a very disputed thing, and a lot of people HATE using it another way, but that was hideous.. Try and find the issues.

Now, looking at it cleaned up (a lot), as I do in a lot of questions:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; //i usually place a newline here, but leave it for others
main()
{                    //I believe its easier to solve missing brace problems this way
    double a = 0;    //this just looks cleaner to me with spaces
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter a number" << endl;
        double b;
        cin >> b;
        a += b;
    }                //it should be unacceptable to do } then another statement, in my eyes
    a/=5;
    if(a==1)
    {                //normally, I would just leave these out, but not in edits
        cout << "a is 1" >> endl;
    }
    else if(a==2)
    {
        cout << "a is 2" >> endl;
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            a %= 2;
            string b = "this is really bad code"
            cout >> b;
        }
    else
    {
       cout << "a is not 1 o 2" << endl;
    }
}
```

That is a lot easier for (at least me) to read.

I have seen worse examples of this, with much larger code.

Here are my **proposals** for style requirements

- All code should maintain the same style throughout it (dont selectively `double a; double b;` then place them on new lines later)
- Just for debugging purposes, braces should be on newlines
- If you place a lot of code, you should use comments to indicate where you **think** the problem is, or state that you have tried these (...) steps and they could not reveal it.
- Maintain a neat style (my general rule is: **tab as if you are using python**)
- Explain (using comments) any complex data structures

If every question followed those, there would be fewer moments of me yelling at the screen and scratching my head. Plus, sometimes I have found that in changing code over to this style one finds a lot of the common bracing, semicolon, wrong angle issues and fixes them, leaving only the complex bugs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your first code example doesn't even compile.

Comment: I am aware. It was not intended to. Neither of them should. They are missing semicolons, braces, and angle brackets facing the wrong direction. The question is about styles, and a real world example would be a new programmer who cant figure out why his/her code wont compile

Comment: Forcing a coding standard on a user is like forcing a user to wear Nordstrom vs. H&M. A particular user's style is their own, and forcing them to change it every time they need to post code (especially lengthy code) would take away some of the incentive to post questions. Plus, newbies wouldn't adhere anyway. The Java tag's newest questions look like a bomb went off. It'd be a failed effort from the start; one more thing to moderate vs. editing and fixing the really obtuse offenders.

Comment: You can change what the requirements are. Or remove those that seem out of bounds. With Java, I believe the programmers read better with same line braces, variables defined on the fly, etc. With C, not so.

Comment: example: just saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640964/c-string-alteration

Comment: `With Java, I believe the programmers read better with same line braces` I disagree entirely, personally. These all seem like **your** favored ways to read/write code. Why should we all conform to your style as opposed to mine? Or Skeet's? Or Atwood's? Or any style? Being able to read code is subjective; everyone is going to enjoy reading one piece of code more than another.

Comment: I didn't say this. My view is that for each language, we should stick to an accepted format for posting questions. Brace style aside, the other points are big, especially the tabbing (since SO is weird and usually screws it up), and the **comments**

Comment: If users don't properly comment their code to the point the code is cryptic, it should be flagged as such if the question cannot support it.

Comment: should we ban trolls?

Comment: Are you insinuating I'm a troll? This is marked as [discusson](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion). I am discussing. If you're not, then my answer would be no. Flag their troll-content, and let the system make the decision -- just like *every other user*.

Comment: Then, let us carry on discussing. Would you not agree that instead of flagging things that are horrible, we just make it a policy: please do it automatically, so we dont have to flag them

Comment: I would not agree. Two reasons of many: your code example one **doesn't compile**. The first mistake I saw of the obvious many was a `for` loop not properly closed. Blocks like that might need to be closed somewhere that a computer will muck up. Code snippets are also susceptible to this; what about XML snippets where closing tags aren't relevant? What will the beautifier do?

Comment: Second scenario is code that already adheres to a standard and where whitespacing makes more sense than '*standardized*' formatting - for instance, new-line escapes on C Macros, which are very commonly aligned to column 80/81

Comment: That is what discussion is for. You seem to be really stuck on my example. Should I cook up one with a runtime error instead of a compile time one?

Comment: No, because I think the cons vastly outweigh the pros here to begin with.

Comment: You have about as good a chance of training the wildebeest to format their code as training them to ask good questions. Look how well _that_ has been going lately.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the formatting rules change, the point is **there will always be someone who has a hard time reading that format of code**. It's a useless endeavor and involves even **more** server processing power.

Comment: I dont know that they were commonly aligned to col 80/81. I said nothing about a spacing requirement, just gave my style of code afterwards as an example since I have a very neatly organized style (in my eyes). @mrjoltcola it isnt a training, its just an etiquette. Try to make it look appealing to the person sifting through it. I am sorry that you dislike my suggestions. Please, tell the world what you would like to see.

Comment: It's actually the [Google Standard](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) which *many* projects strictly adhere to.

Comment: Very strict as opposed to my five things, but if i would publicly be better, there is **absolutely** no reason not to use it

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is asking too much. I have to agree with this post.